# Why does Google Chrome regularly give an ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED error?

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome

Chrome, at least on Mac OS, regularly stops loading pages and instead returns ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED; the only thing that I have ever managed to do is restart the router which tends to fix it. Of course this only is a plausible solution if I am the only person using the router at that time.

Googling around provides a lot of pages that suggest things in the vein of "open the car doors and shut them again", but nothing really seems to actually fix the issue. It is clearly a chrome-only thing as other browsers (both Firefox and Safari at least) do not have the issue at the exact same time.

So my question is twofold:

- What exactly is this issue?
- Is there actually any other way to fix it other than frustratingly unplugging my router and plugging it back in, or failing that, switching browsers entirely?

(Yes, I am a bit frustrated at the moment; I am using my phone's hotspot because that works perfectly well, but switching back to wifi means pages essentially stop loading 90% of the time)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regularly getting ERR\_NETWORK\_CHANGED errors in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/747735/regularly-getting-err-network-changed-errors-in-chrome)

Comment: That question does seem a lot more useful than the majority of hits on google, I'll take a look around and see if it fixes things next time this error arises...

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this error myself some weeks ago. Did some testing and found out that some of the onboard apps of macOS seem to trigger this problem. I also observed, that this had a correlation with slow loading web pages, to the effect that a page that took more time to load had a higher probability of being interrupted by this error. So this could also be more likely to happen on a WiFi with a slow connection.

In my case I had two instances of Safari running at the same time (in two different user sessions). After closing Safari in one session the error ceased to appear. Starting up Safari again and the error was back. So there seems to be a strong indication that some of the built-in software of macOS don't play well with Chromiums (other browsers of the same heritage like Edge was affected likeway) "network change detection".

Some people on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOSBeta/comments/wgb6jw/err_network_changed_constantly_since_dp2/) reported, that this problem can also be triggered (and solved by closing) the native Home.app and Notes.app.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue since Mac OS Sonoma.
I was going crazy.
I've been looking for the reason for months. And finally, it was a problem with xcode and my iphone... I disabled the pairing between the two. And since then I no longer have the problem! Finally ! I hope it will help you. (if you are a dev who uses xcode)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.